# ¿Como puedo realizar un random de imagenes en Angular?

Tags: angular

Estoy realizando una pagina web en Angular y tengo que hacer un random de imagenes pero no se como hacerlo en este Framework

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste buscar en google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si las imágenes son url:

> En el html

```
<img [src]="imagenAleatoria">
<button type="button" (click)="obtenerImagen()"></button>
```

> En el ts

```
imagenAleatoria = '';
imagenes:any[]=['url1','url2','url3'];
ngOnInit(){
 this.obtenerImagen();
}

obtenerImagen(){
  const index = this.obtenerIndex(0, this.imagenes.length-1);
  this.imagenAleatoria = this.imagenes[index]
}

obtenerIndex(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

Las funciones de javascript funcionan igual:[math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)